# Install with pip into conda environment: No module

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip, conda

I would like to install http://pythonhosted.org/pyswarm/ but after

```
source activate myenv
pip install pyswarm
```

and then

```
from pyswarm import pso
```

I get

```
ImportError: No module named 'pyswarm'
```

I do find `lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyswarm-0.7-py3.5.egg` in my conda environment though. What's the matter?

Answer (score 0):

First find out which pip are you referencing

```
which pip
```

If it is /usr/bin/python2.7 or something like that, then that is the reason because you are using pip of different python version.

Try

```
which pip3  # If it belongs to your myenv, then do the next line
pip3 install pyswarm
```